# Mathematical expression for a cross-correlation matrix

Tags: matrix, notation, cross-correlation

Given the matrices $A_{p\times q}$ and $B_{p\times q}$ with $p>q$ the cross-correlation matrix in R is calculated as:

```
cor(A,B)
```

The underlaying code for this is:

```
n <- nrow(A)
C <- diag(n) - matrix(1/n,n,n)
D <- diag(apply(A,2,sd))
Xs1 <- C %*% A %*% solve(D)

D2 <- diag(apply(B,2,sd))
Xs2 <- C %*% B %*% solve(D2)

R <- t(Xs1) %*% Xs2 / (n-1) #=cor(A,B)
```

I would like to notate mathematically the routine, however I get stuck at `D <- diag(apply(A,2, sd))` which is not the same as doing `diag(t(A) %*% A)/n`. Anyways, I would like to materialize this code in a common matrix notation. Thank you.

Comment: `apply(A, 2, sd)` calculates the (sample) standard deviations of columns of `A`. Using `diag(...)` takes those SDs and puts them on a diagonal matrix where the $ii$-th element is the standard deviation of the $i$-th column of `A`

Comment: Thank you @jcken, maybe you could also answer the question